# How to auto-refresh a page without blinking using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a polling app where the page gets results from the database every 5second but the page blinks so bad that it disrupts the whole experience.

I'm currently using Jquery `setInterval ()` method.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function (event) {
    // refreshes every 5 seconds
    setInterval(refresh, 5000);
      //event.preventDefault()
   // setInterval(refreshButton, 20000);  


});


function refresh() {
/* fade in the element with content id*/ 
   $("#content").load(window.location.href + "#content").fadeIn();

}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;"> 


 <center>  <button class="button button5" id="content"></button></center>

</div>

</div>
```

My question now is that how do I update a page without the blinking effect. In such a way where users won't see the page blinking.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you try to change HTML ??

Comment: What `fadeIn` is for? Did you use `fadeOut` before?

Comment: Change HTML? what's that?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Yes. I don't use `fadeOut` before.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make your refresh function like this?

```
function refresh() {
   /* fade in the element with content id*/ 
   $("#content").fadeOut(100);    
   $("#content").load(window.location.href + "#content")
   $("#content").fadeIn(100);
}
```

Even more better:

```
function refresh() {
       /* fade in the element with content id*/ 
       var data = window.location.href + "#content";
        $("#content").fadeToggle(200, function(){
            $("#content").load(window.location.href + "#content")
        });
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Comment: Yes you will use setInterval(); console.log(data); if nothing showing up.. .... I have just changed refresh method... that function only .... rest will remain same

Comment: `console.log(data)` is returning the link of the page. The whole page disappears after a few seconds as well.